Modify All Data - what access/capabilities does it enable
The question may look silly, but I cannot find it anywhere without looking at each Salesforce help article one by one.
I know that this permission gives user full edit rights to all objects and fields, but it also gives the user numerous other privileges like:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sales.email_logs_edit.htm&type=5
I would like to know what is the full list of privileges which will be granted to the user when I assign him "Modify All Data" system permission.

This is as close to a documented list as you'll get: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384401&type=1 .

Thanks @identigral. I am just a bit worried as there is nothing regarding submitting an email log. I am afraid the Article can skip more things...
